# List directories in zip and rar files

Tags: r, zip, data-extraction, unrar

I trying to do a data frame/list/vector with a list of folders inside a zip and rar file.

I have a folder with a lot of zip and rar files;
Each zip and rar file has one folder and inside this folder has a lot of folders and files;
I would get the names of these folders inside a zipped folder;

I try:

```
unzip(zipfile = "teste1.zip", list = TRUE)
```

and it show me:

```
                            Name Length                Date
1                        teste1/      0 2022-08-03 15:49:00
2            teste1/Nova pasta1/      0 2022-08-03 15:50:00
3 teste1/Nova pasta1/texto11.txt      0 2022-08-03 15:49:00
4              teste1/texto1.txt      0 2022-08-03 15:49:00
```

But I would like to get just the names of second directory (Nova pasta 1)

Thanks a lot

Comment: For zip files, use the builtin `unzip` function, with argument `list = T`. Not sure there is the equivalent for RAR files. There is still the possibility to parse the output of `unrar -l`.

Answer (score 0):

for ZIP:

```
unzip -l archive.zip
```

for RAR:

```
unrar -l archive.rar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip zip files in R using the base R function `unzip`. I am not sure if there is a similar solution for RAR files. Once unzipped, you can use the base R function `list.files()` to list the names of the files and folders in any directory on your computer, e.g. `list.files(path="mypath")`.

Comment: No need to actually unzip the file to get the listing from the `unzip` function. Look up the option `list = T` in the documentation.